# plug-in com.salesforce.ide.ui was unable to load class error

Tags: ide, eclipse

I get the following error message whenever I create a **New Project** or Apex class or VF page.[image: Problem Opening Wizard]

I tried reinstalling, but it still gives the same error again and again.
eclipse version: Mars.1 Release (4.5.1)
Force IDE:version 35

Comment: Which version of eclipse you are using and what was the forcecom-ide version ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the Eclipse Mars download for Java EE, rather than Java.

Comment: I have the same issue. I use Mars for Java EE and tried both the versions of Force.com plugin and the OS is mac. Have I missed something?